# Google map clustering in android

Tags: android

I want to change  clustering icon like below in android. In a circle there will be a one imageview and one textview.

[image]

My code for custom icon

```
  private class ItemRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<ClusterPopupList> {
    private final IconGenerator mIconGenerator = new IconGenerator(getApplicationContext());
    private final IconGenerator mClusterIconGenerator = new IconGenerator(getApplicationContext());
    private final int mDimension;

    public ItemRenderer() {
        super(getApplicationContext(), map, mClusterManager);

        View multiProfile = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.multi_profile,null);
        mClusterIconGenerator.setContentView(multiProfile);
        mImageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        mDimension = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_profile_image);
        mImageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(mDimension, mDimension));
        mIconGenerator.setContentView(mImageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(ClusterPopupList item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        mImageView.setImageResource(item.profilePhoto);
        Bitmap icon = mIconGenerator.makeIcon();
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
        super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<ClusterPopupList> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        List<Drawable> profilePhotos = new ArrayList<Drawable>(Math.min(4, cluster.getSize()));
        int width = mDimension;
        int height = mDimension;

        for (ClusterPopupList p : cluster.getItems()) {
            // Draw 4 at most.
            if (profilePhotos.size() == 4) break;
            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(p.profilePhoto);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
            profilePhotos.add(drawable);
        }

        Bitmap icon = mClusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize()));
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClusterRendered(Cluster<ClusterPopupList> cluster, Marker marker) {
        super.onClusterRendered(cluster, marker);
    }

    @Override
    public ClusterPopupList getClusterItem(Marker marker) {

        return super.getClusterItem(marker);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster<ClusterPopupList> cluster) {
        return cluster.getSize() > 1;
    }
}
```

multi_profile.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_cluster_count"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Bubble.TextAppearance.Light"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/custom_profile_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/custom_profile_padding"
    android:layout_below="@id/image"
    android:text="150"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
    android:textColor="@color/theme_color"
    android:alpha=".8"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Output :

[image]

I want to achieve cluster icon like first image in a circle. I have used circle background in relative layout, but that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to remove background

```
mClusterIconGenerator.setBackground(null)
```

> Set the background to a given Drawable, or remove the background.
> @param background the Drawable to use as the background, or null to remove the background.

Answer (score 1):

```
    mClusterIconGenerator.setBackground(AndroidUtil.getDrawable(R.drawable.cluster_backgroud));
```

Comment: this is the simplest way to do and in background file u only need to add solid as transparent

Answer (score 0):

From [the Google Maps documentation site:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering#custom)

Customize the marker clusters

The `ClusterManager` constructor creates a `DefaultClusterRenderer` and a `NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm`. You can change the `ClusterRenderer` and the Algorithm using the `setAlgorithm(Algorithm<T> algorithm)` and `setRenderer(ClusterRenderer<T> view) methods of ClusterManager`.

You can implement `ClusterRenderer` to customize the rendering of the clusters. `DefaultClusterRenderer` provides a good base to start from. By subclassing `DefaultClusterRenderer`, you can override the defaults.

[image]

Comment: I have done that.But icon is showing in a rectangle like above.But i want circular.

Comment: Well, that when you need to start programming to customize it how you want it. Post your code, what you have tried, what results you had, what is exactly not working for you, etc

Comment: It looks like either `DefaultClusterRenderer ` or `IconGenerator` are adding that ballon background to your custom markers.

Comment: Thank you Robert for your answer, I have solved the issue.

Comment: What was the solution?