# map clustering in android in appcelerator titanium

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I am using titanium SDK 5.0.0.GA.I have lot of map annonation on mapview.I want to load all annonation on mapview and display it as per map zoom level.I know there is one way for doing that is cluster map but I am not sure how to achieve this in android using titanium framework.

Look at [Google map clustering in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699348/google-map-clustering-in-android)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a JavaScript-based library called [Ti.MarkerManager](https://github.com/AppWerft/Ti.MarkerManager) to hide pins in certain zoom-levels. Unfortunately, at least iOS does not offer Clustering in their native `MKMapView`, yet. The Android-part could be implemented as a new feature in [Ti.Map](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.map) Android.